# Android Theme.Dialog gives me an error

Tags: android

When I want to add this code on my app it gives me this : "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped".
Is because I added this line : `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

I tried to add this line too `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"` but is still not working

```
<activity android:name=".About"  android:label="@string/about_title" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"> </activity>
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: It's hard to help without a logcat and some code. Please refer to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Share your code or your logcat, please.

Comment: @style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog

Comment: Which Base activity you are using in About. If you are extending AppCompatActivity then use the style of AppCompat.

Answer (score 1):

TRY:
 adding android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" to your application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<activity android:name=".About"  android:label="@string/about_title" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"> </activity>
```